# create custom facebook page using html

Tags: facebook

is there a canvas for Facebook pages like there is for facebook apps where I can Insert an html page? I want to create a webpage with a width of 600 using html, javasript css, and than embed it into facebook the same way I do it with a regular facebook App. But how do I do this in a FB Page? I don't see any canvas for a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being that FBML will be depreciated come January 1, 2012 going that route will not be real viable.

However there are a few applications popping up on Facebook that filling that void. I would suggest checking out this article: http://patrickpowers.net/2011/03/no-more-static-fbml-no-problem/

Comment: How can you enable a simple html block in a FB page. I want toenable <a>hello world!</a>. Where can I put this HTML. With apps I put it on my webpage and I add the page as a canvas to facebook

Answer (score 0):

This currently only can be done using **Page tab** for an application.
Page tab canvas is 520 pixels wide and is generally an iframe loading your URL. You can place your resources (html/js/css/etc) on any hosting/server you own.

Read the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Static HTML iframe tabs](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=190322544333196) app, this app allows you to input html. i think this app is best replacement of Static FBML app.